# Wired network connection drops every 30 minutes

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

Recently, my desktop running Windows 8 64-bit has been losing network connectivity consistently every 30 minutes. The machine is connected via ethernet to a Trendnet TPL-307E powerline networking unit whose counterpart downstairs is connected to a Buffalo WHR-G300N running DD-WRT, which is connected to the internet via a Motorola SB5100 SURFboard connected to a coax serve by Comcast.

I have a command window open running `ping -t google.com`, and every 30 minutes two pings will fail. This causes my corporate VPN to disconnect and generally disrupts my workflow. When it happens, the monitoring lights on the powerline unit are still green, so the problem appears to be elsewhere. There are no event log messages at the time of the outage except those from the VPN client saying it disconnected. Any ideas on why this might happen?

Comment: I wonder if there is a problem with renegotiating your computers DHCP lease.  You might be able to change the lease length time in your router or change to a static IP on your computer to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Do you have a second machine (e.g. a laptop) to test with. It would be interesting to see if that also looses the connection every 30 minutes. (Starting with a test at the same outlet, and if an error occurs moving it to the buffalo, testing there etc etc)